# Extend PHPDoc/PHPStorm Documention in another file

Tags: php, documentation, phpstorm, phpdoc

I have a class (which I'll call `Example`) which implements the `__call()` method. This method allows the class to be extended to have additional calls (based on other data). For this question, I'll assume one of those is `getDemoData()`.

This `getDemoData()` function would be available if it had a value in an array with a key `Demo`. The return value would be a specific class, in this case, named `Demo`.

Is it possible to some how extend the PHPDoc documentation (either due to PHPDoc directly, or something special in PHPStorm itself) which would allow me to say in `Demo` that `Example` has a method named `Example::getDemoData()`.

I know I can use the `@method` tag from within the class itself, but I don't know if I can use it outside of that class (if I can, I'm not sure the syntax).

Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK: nope. Unless (maybe) if you are using some framework and there is a plugin for that framework which can provide such extended info.

Comment: @samanime Did you achieve this? I'm looking for the same thing now.

Comment: No. I ended up using ashnazg's answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best you can do in that scenario is to use the @see tag in Demo's class docblock:

```
/**
 * @see Example::getDemoData()
 */
class Demo {}
```

assuming that you did indeed put @method in Example's class docblock:

```
/**
 * @method Demo getDemoData()
 */
class Example {}
```

Comment: Thanks. I had thought of that, but I would prefer not to put the method in to my object, since it only exists if certain other things are hooked up. However, it's probably as close as I'll get. I'll let this go for another day or too, but I'll probably end up accepting this answer.